# Solution to creating thiessen polygons in spyder python?

Tags: python, spyder

Currently working on a project which utilizes data from a .mat file. My goal is to use thiessen polygons to see where the data is occurring, and at what intensity. Any tips?

I currently have the following code to determine Euclidean distances of points to 9 gauge points:

```
for x in range(0,127):
    for y in range(0,127):
        EuD1 = np.sqrt((x - 40)**2 + (y - 30)**2)
        #print(EuD1)
        EuD2 = np.sqrt((x - 20)**2 + (y - 60)**2)
        EuD3 = np.sqrt((x - 50)**2 + (y - 10)**2)
        EuD4 = np.sqrt((x - 60)**2 + (y - 60)**2)
        EuD5 = np.sqrt((x - 80)**2 + (y - 20)**2)
        EuD6 = np.sqrt((x - 20)**2 + (y - 20)**2)
        EuD7 = np.sqrt((x - 115)**2 + (y - 110)**2)
        EuD8 = np.sqrt((x - 90)**2 + (y - 60)**2)
        EuD9 = np.sqrt((x - 20)**2 + (y - 115)**2)
```